# Извлечение данных из БД с помощью Hibernate

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

Здравствуйте,

осваиваю Hibernate фреймворк. Возникло следующее затруднение.

Есть программа которая создает 2 объекта типа `Employee` и 1 типа `Department`.

```
public class App {




  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Department department = new Department("java");
    session.save(department);

    session.persist(new Employee("Jakab Gipsz",department));
    session.persist(new Employee("Captain Nemo",department));



    session.getTransaction().commit();

    Query q = session.createQuery("From Employee ");

    List<Employee> resultList = q.list();

    System.out.println("num of employess:" + resultList.size());



    for (Employee next : resultList) {
        System.out.println("next employee: " + next);
    }



 }

}
```

И в конце в консоле выдается надпись:

`num of employess:2
next employee: Employee [id=2, name=Jakab Gipsz, department=java]
next employee: Employee [id=3, name=Captain Nemo, department=java]`

После проверяю базу данных (использую apache derby) там все эти данные есть.

Далее в качестве эксперимента я хочу извлечь данные и в этот раз я запускаю уже программу:

```
 public class App {




  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Query q = session.createQuery("From Employee ");

    List<Employee> resultList = q.list();

    System.out.println("num of employess:" + resultList.size());



    for (Employee next : resultList) {
        System.out.println("next employee: " + next);
    }

  }
}
```

Программа в консоли выдает

`num of employess:0`

И после выполнения этой программы созданная ранее в БД таблица стирается.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему я не могу извлечь данные во 2ой сессии, и как это правильно сделать, чтобы данные не стирались ?

==============================

Файл настроек "hibernate.cfg.xml":

```
<property name="connection.url">
 jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test;create=true;user=dd;password=123
</property>
<property name="connection.username">dd</property>
<property name="connection.password">123</property>
<property name="dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
</property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>



 <mapping class="com.mastertheboss.domain.Employee" />
 <mapping class="com.mastertheboss.domain.Department" />
```

Класс `Employee`:

```
@Entity
@Table

public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
private Department department;

public Employee() {}

public Employee(String name, Department department) {
    this.name = name;
    this.department = department;
}


public Employee(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", department="
            + department.getName() + "]";
}

}
```

Comment: Какой значение параметра `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`? И укажите файл настроек хибернейта.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, такого файла у меня нет. Добавил что есть. Это конфигурационный файл `hibernate.cfg.xml` и класс `Employee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в файле `hibernate.cfg.xml` стоит параметр

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

он означает, что таблицы будут создаваться каждый раз при запуске проекта.

Можно заменить `create` на `update` и тогда таблицы в БД не будут пересоздаваться, а будут обновляться с текущими настройками сущностей, т.е. добавление колонок, новых таблиц (все данные в таблице при этом должны остаться). Или после первого запуска приложение закомментируйте этот параметр.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, за подробный ответ. Действительно после исправления с `create`->`update` таблица перестала стираться.